# How can I change keyboard keys result?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

When we press <kbd>A</kbd> key on keyboard, the OS wil actually write the `A` character as a result of doing so. How can I change keyboard keys result?

For example if I press the <kbd>A</kbd> key on my keyboard, I would want the OS to write `B`,  `Ä` or `آ`.

Answer (score 0):

I find. We must modify X keyboard layout.
[XKB in Xorg wiki](http://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/)
[An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/xkb.html)
[custom keyboard layout](http://www.dotkam.com/2007/06/25/custom-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu-or-just-linux-2/)